# CMake was unable to find build program

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors

I am struggling with my cmake setup to start compiling my code. The existing answers to this problem couldn't solve my issues so I have to start a new post.

I get the following error after running `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe .` using the cmd prompt (Windows 10):

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:56 (try_compile):
  Failed to configure test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

At first here is my CMakeList.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
set(OPENBLAS_LIB_DIR "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib")
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/make.exe")

project(PROJECT_1 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 23)


add_executable(PROJECT_1 src/main.c)

# I'm not sure about the following but thats another problem I want to solve

set(OPENBLAS_LIB_DIR "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib")
find_library(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY NAMES openblas PATHS ${OPENBLAS_LIB_DIR})

message("OpenBLAS library not found ${LIBRARY}")

if(NOT OPENBLAS_LIBRARY)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "OpenBLAS library not found ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH}")
endif()

find_package(OpenBLAS REQUIRED)
#find_library(OpenBLAS REQUIRED)
#include_directories(${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
target_link_libraries(PROJECT_1 OpenBLAS::OpenBLAS)
```

Furthermore I use MSYS2 with MinGW64. I downloaded several packages from the getting startet instructions with msys2/mingw64.exe.

I already checked the environment variables for "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\" which is present. I may also messed something up when I also installed TDM compilers. I uninstalled it so that my code finds the gcc compiler from MinGW not from TDM.

I also tried using `SET( CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM c:/MinGW-32/bin/make.exe FORCE )`

The CMake-gui could somehow compile my code but throughs the following error and couldn't find the openblas library which is installed using the MSYS prompt for MinGW64:

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/cc.exe - skipped
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
OpenBLAS library not found 
Configuring done (1.7s)
```

I may have messed something up through try and error so I need your advice.

Comment: Do not confuse **build program** with **compiler**. The first one, which is expected by the `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`, is `make` or like utility. Also, the error `CMake was unable to find a build program ...` is emitted when CMake processes `project()` call. Setting variables after that call won't help.

Comment: Of course, thank you! But I still get a similar error (see updated version above).

Comment: As far as I remember, `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` should be set as a CACHE variable. BTW, you could set it from command line, like you do with `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variable.

Comment: Yeah that should fix it, even if I couldn't get it run via cmd prompt. However, the cmake-gui was able to configure the file but wasn't able to generate an .exe.

Comment: If you use msys2 install your MinGW and all open source packages using pacman.  Then run `cmake` from the terminal of the msys2 environment you are using and it should work automatically.

Comment: I got rid of the issue by using clang instead of gcc, which seems weird to me. I don't understand why gcc should not be able to use blas or lapacke.